# Dynamic Energy Dissipation (Qualitative question)

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, energy

"Every dynamic system tends to dissipate its energy to the environment in the fastest way possible."
The above statement sounds intuitively right to me. After all, isn't this the principle behind all spontaneous processes?

My questions:

1. Is the statements true or false?
2. What source can I quote as to the truth of falsity of the same?

Comment: Hi vkarve; please don't edit the answer into the question like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid the statement is pretty vacuous, although technically true. Yes, systems dissipate energy to their environment. Do they do this in the "fastest way possible"? Well, they dissipate energy according to the laws of physics describing whatever process is governing the exchange of energy. So, yeah, they dissipate energy in "the fastest way possible", but it's also "the slowest way possible", because in fact it's "the only way possible".